# Deployed Silverlight application exception when calling a WCF Service

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, deployment

The silverlight application runs but when it calls the service I get:

**An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.
   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at SalesSimplicityPO_SL.POSvc.GetPurchaseOrdersCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at SalesSimplicityPO_SL.About.mySvc_GetPurchaseOrdersCompleted(Object sender, GetPurchaseOrdersCompletedEventArgs e)
   at SalesSimplicityPO_SL.POSvc.POSvcClient.OnGetPurchaseOrdersCompleted(Object state)**

I load and call my web service like..

```
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost/POSystem/POSvc.svc"));
    POSvc.POSvcClient mySvc = new POSvc.POSvcClient(binding, address); 
    mySvc.InsertPOCompleted += new EventHandler<SalesSimplicityPO_SL.POSvc.InsertPOCompletedEventArgs>(mySvc_InsertPOCompleted);
    mySvc.InsertPOAsync(InitialsTextBox.Text.ToString(), DescTextBox.Text.ToString(), ClientTextBox.Text.ToString());
```

Works great in debug....

What am I doing wrong to get this error?

---

**Update:**

I don't really understand Why it fixed it but this fixed it..  Maybe someone can offer some info...

I changed

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost/POSystem/POSvc.svc"));
```

TO

```
 EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../POSvc.svc"));
```

Comment: Did you `Check InnerException for exception details`?

Comment: haha unless im an idiot (which is possible... ) that is the inner exception is up there.. it begins with  System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs....

Comment: That is the outer exception, which is in the `Error` property of the EventArgs.  Check `e.Error.InnerException`.

Comment: Ok That makes sense now.. brings up more questions but thats the beauty of it all right?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because silverlight does not resolve virtual path as ASP.NET does. To go to the root ASP.NET folder you have to use Application.Current.Host.Source

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand Why it fixed it but this fixed it..  Maybe someone can offer some info...

I changed

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost/POSystem/POSvc.svc"));
```

TO

```
 EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source, "../POSvc.svc"));
```

Comment: Moved this additional info to an update on the main question.